# how to label each levels with day break in pinescript

Tags: pine-script

```
plot(ab1, color= wtdo[0] >= ab1 ? color.purple: color.blue )
label.new(bar_index, ab1, "R1", style=label.style_none)

plot(ab2, color= wtdo[0] >= ab2 ? color.purple : color.blue, linewidth=2)
plot(ab3, color= wtdo[0] >= ab3 ? color.purple: color.blue)
plot(ab4, color= wtdo[0] >= ab4 ? color.purple: color.blue, linewidth=2)
//p2= plot(ab5, color= wtdo[0] >= ab4 ? color.black: color.black, linewidth=3)
plot(ab6, color= wtdo[0] >= ab6 ? color.purple: color.blue, linewidth=2 )
plot(ab7, color= wtdo[0] >= ab7 ? color.purple: color.blue )
plot(ab8, color= wtdo[0] >= ab8 ? color.purple: color.blue, linewidth=2 )
plot(ab9, color= wtdo[0] >= ab9 ? color.purple: color.blue )
plot(ab10, color= wtdo[0] >= ab10 ? color.purple: color.blue, linewidth=2 )
plot(ab11, color= wtdo[0] >= ab11 ? color.purple: color.blue )
plot(ab12, color= wtdo[0] >= ab12 ? color.purple: color.blue, linewidth=2 )
plot(ab13, color= wtdo[0] >= ab13 ? color.purple: color.blue )
plot(ab14, color= wtdo[0] >= ab14 ? color.purple: color.blue, linewidth=2 )
plot(ab15, color= wtdo[0] >= ab15 ? color.purple: color.blue )
plot(ab16, color= wtdo[0] >= ab16 ? color.purple: color.blue , linewidth=2)
plot(ab17, color= wtdo[0] >= ab17 ? color.purple: color.blue )
plot(ab26, color= wtdo[0] >= ab26 ? color.purple: color.blue, linewidth=2)
plot(ab27, color= wtdo[0] >= ab27 ? color.purple: color.blue)
plot(ab28, color= wtdo[0] >= ab28 ? color.purple: color.blue, linewidth=2)
plot(ab29, color= wtdo[0] >= ab29 ? color.purple: color.blue)
plot(ab30, color= wtdo[0] >= ab30 ? color.purple: color.blue, linewidth=2)
plot(ab31, color= wtdo[0] >= ab31 ? color.purple: color.blue)
plot(ab32, color= wtdo[0] >= ab32 ? color.purple: color.blue, linewidth=2)
plot(ab33, color= wtdo[0] >= ab33 ? color.purple: color.blue, linewidth=2)
//fill(p1,p2, color=color.green, transp=70)
```

I have some plots that calculates levels in each day but i wish to plot a label for each level each day. But iam getting the label in the last or current day only.

[image]

Can someone help me how to plot my label at each day seperately.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could use labels like this:

```
//@version=4
study("", "", true)
f_tickFormat() =>
    _s = tostring(syminfo.mintick)
    _s := str.replace_all(_s, "25", "00")
    _s := str.replace_all(_s, "5",  "0")
    _s := str.replace_all(_s, "1",  "0")

ma = sma(close, 30)
newDay = change(time("D"))
if newDay
    label.new(bar_index, ma, tostring(ma, f_tickFormat()))
plot(ma)
```

[image]